# How to plot an arrow when Fisher transform crosses over?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to plot an arrow every time the Fisher transform is crossing. So far I could draw arrows showing the uptrend or the downtrend, but I can't figure out how to store the previous state so that only a switch in trend is indicated.

So, when you create a new Fisher transform, you can see the 2 variables fish1 and fish2. Each time when previously fish1 > fish2 and now fish1 < fish2, an arrow should be plotted.
Below is the full code using plotshape().

```
//@version=3
study(title="Fisher Transform", shorttitle="Fisher")
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")

high_ = highest(hl2, len)
low_ = lowest(hl2, len)

round_(val) => val > .99 ? .999 : val < -.99 ? -.999 : val

value = 0.0
value := round_(.66 * ((hl2 - low_) / max(high_ - low_, .001) - .5) + .67 * nz(value[1]))

fish1 = 0.0
fish1 := .5 * log((1 + value) / max(1 - value, .001)) + .5 * nz(fish1[1])

fish2 = fish1[1]

plotshape(fish1 > fish2, style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, color=green, size=size.small, text="Buy") 
plotshape(fish1 < fish2, style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.belowbar, color=red, size=size.small, text="Sell") 


hline(1.5, color=orange)
hline(0.75)
hline(0, color=orange)
hline(-0.75)
hline(-1.5, color=orange)
plot(fish1, color=blue, title="Fisher")
plot(fish2, color=orange, title="Trigger")
```

Is there a function that would allow me to plot the arrow only when the condition 'is greater' is changing to 'is lower'?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crossover()` and `crossunder()` are the functions you are looking for.

> **crossover**
>
> The `x`-series is defined as having crossed over `y`-series if the
>   value of `x` is greater than the value of `y` and the value of `x` was
>   less than the value of `y` on the bar immediately preceding the
>   current bar.
>
> **crossunder**
>
> The `x`-series is defined as having crossed under `y`-series if the
>   value of `x` is less than the value of `y` and the value of `x` was
>   greater than the value of `y` on the bar immediately preceding the
>   current bar.

```
plotshape(crossover(fish1, fish2), style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, color=green, size=size.small, text="Buy") 
plotshape(crossunder(fish1, fish2), style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.belowbar, color=red, size=size.small, text="Sell")
```